# What’s the term used to define a terrestrial being that moves by using six limbs?

Tags: bio-mechanics

I know that Bipedal locomotion would describe how beings like humans and ostriches get around.

Quadrupedal locomotion describes how beings like dogs and cats move around.

What about insects, specifically, a cockroach? I believe a cockroach has six “legs”, what would be the term used to describe that type of locomotion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hexapedal**. From [wiki > Hexapedal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hexapedal)

> Having six legs

Note that *[Hexapoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexapoda)* is a taxonomic group including insects and the smaller groups that are Collembola, Protura, and Diplura.

Comment: Thanks. I actually searched that before the post. Based on the feedback from google, the subject must be A.) Highly complicated B.) Lacks much interest, or C.)All of the above.

Comment: What is `the subject` in your comment? I don't really understand your comment. Do you think 'hexapodal' is the word you were looking for?

Comment: Well, the subject is “Hexapedal Locomotion “. Not much data

Comment: Oh do you just men the term is rarely used? Yes, I am sure it is very rarely used!

Comment: I’m an electronics hobbyists, and I’m enthusiastic about robotics. Wanted to know how much man understood about hexapedal motion. Doesn’t seem like much so far.

Comment: Right.... I'm sure there's quite a bit on the subject though. But anyway.... did your question got its answer? If yes, you can click on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: I have seen a couple programs where professionals from universities were demonstrating big-like robots...now that I think about it, I think their “bugs” only had four legs. Hexapedal locomotion must be a complicated concept.

Comment: Searched [for six legged robot on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=six+legged+robot) and found quite a few examples. None of them are particularly fast. Anyway... talking robots is not the point of your post.